# Compare two yaml file and get matching elements from first file based on key

Tags: awk, yaml, diff, yq

I am trying to compare these two `YAML` files and trying to extract the key-value pair from the first file if key matches between these two files. Look at the expected output for more clarity.

**YAML File 1:**

```
  COMMON-VAR: "[\n  { \"DESC\": \"A\", \"O\": \"h\", \"confidence\":0.8 },\n  { \"DESC\": \"B\", \"O\": \"u\", \"C\":0.8 }\n { \"DESC\": \"A\", \"O\": \"h\", \"confidence\":0.8 },\n "
  LASTNAME: "D"
  FIRSTNAME: "JOHN"
  UNKNOWN: "!!"
```

**YAML File 2:**

```
  COMMON-VAR: "[\n  { \"DESC\": \"A\", \"O\": \"h\", \"confidence\":0.8 },\n  { \"DESC\": \"B\", \"O\": \"u\", \"C\":0.8 }\n"
  LASTNAME: "E"
  FIRSTNAME: "JOHN"
  ADDRESS: "SanJose, CA"
  ZIP: "09817"
```

**Expected output:**

```
  COMMON-VAR: "[\n  { \"DESC\": \"A\", \"O\": \"h\", \"confidence\":0.8 },\n  { \"DESC\": \"B\", \"O\": \"u\", \"C\":0.8 }\n { \"DESC\": \"A\", \"O\": \"h\", \"confidence\":0.8 },\n "
  LASTNAME: "D"
```

**My Attempt:**

```
join <(sort file1.yaml) <(sort file2.yaml) | awk '$2!=$3{print $1,$3}' | yq e -I4
```

It works when I don't have curly braces in my values, but `awk` fails when I have `{}` in my value in `yaml` file.

Comment: Because I want to just compare the values for the matching keys between two files. In this case the matching keys are `COMMON-VAR`, `LASTNAME` & `FIRSTNAME`.

Comment: The question mentions key, not values: `if key matches`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -F':' '
FNR==NR                    { seen[$1]=$0; next }
$1 in seen && $0!=seen[$1] { print seen[$1] }
' file1.yaml file2.yaml
```

Or, slightly less typing if files are fed in reverse order:

```
awk -F':' '
FNR==NR                    { seen[$1]=$0; next }
$1 in seen && $0!=seen[$1]
' file2.yaml file1.yaml
```

Both of these generate:

```
  COMMON-VAR: "[\n  { \"DESC\": \"A\", \"O\": \"h\", \"confidence\":0.8 },\n  { \"DESC\": \"B\", \"O\": \"u\", \"C\":0.8 }\n { \"DESC\": \"A\", \"O\": \"h\", \"confidence\":0.8 },\n "
  LASTNAME: "D"
```

Comment: This will fail for the new input. Thanks.

Comment: I meant my code will fail if I have `{}` in any of the yaml values because `awk` doesn't print `{}`.

Comment: @JamesBrown Thanks! Gonna go out tonight and go hog wild on the celebration ... spend some of them SO points on ... ummm ... errrr ... wait ... how much are 10K SO pts worth? :-)

Comment: They are worth of a big pile of downvotes. :D

Comment: The array name `seen[]` is idiomatically used to differentiate the first vs subsequent occurrences of a string in the input, e.g. `if ( seen[$1]++ ) do subsequent stuff; else do first stuff`, not to tell if a string existed in a previous file or not, so it somewhat obfuscates your code by using it in that other context. Your code would be clearer if you named the array `map[]` or `file1[]` or `key2val[]` or even `a[]` in this case.